# No display in thee GUI using tkinter dropdown menu

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def functionhi():
    print("hiiiiii")

root = Tk()

pikumenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=pikumenu)

submenu = Menu(pikumenu)

submenu.add_cascade(label="add",menu=submenu)

submenu.add_command(label="do",command=functionhi)

submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label="hiii",command=functionhi)

sourya= Menu(pikumenu)

sourya.add_cascade(label="exit",menu=sourya)

sourya.add_command(label="done",command=lambda:print("hiiii exit "))

root.mainloop()
```

Im not getting any display on the window.

Comment: `submenu.add_cascade(label="add",menu=submenu)` (and similar code for `sourya`) is wrong - you're trying to add these submenus to *themselves*, rather than to the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

When you do add_cascade you need to call it on the Main menu `pikumenu` instead of the submenus `submenu` and `sourya`.

Something else you may want to know for your project is when you define the submenus you might want to do `Menu(pikumenu, tearoff=False)` instead to disable the option for it to be opened in a second window which in my opinion is just really annoying

Fixed Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def functionhi():
    print("hiiiiii")

root = Tk()

pikumenu = Menu(root)


submenu = Menu(pikumenu, tearoff=False)



submenu.add_command(label="do",command=functionhi)

submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label="hiii",command=functionhi)
pikumenu.add_cascade(label="add",menu=submenu)

sourya= Menu(pikumenu, tearoff=False)

sourya.add_command(label="done",command=lambda:print("hiiii exit "))
pikumenu.add_cascade(label="exit",menu=sourya)

root.config(menu=pikumenu)

root.mainloop()
```

I moved some stuff around but it still works